# Inkscape copy shape to several layers

Tags: inkscape

I have a Inkscape Project with about 100 Layers. Every Layer has the same shape ( with others beside that are different ). Now I would like to exchange the shape with a new one.
So far I did this by hand -> selecting every layer, delete the shape and paste the new shape.

Is there any trick to do this more effectively ? Can I paste a shape to more then one layer at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should have used clones instead of copy & pasting the same shape all over.

A possible way to do what you want is to use the scripting capability of Inkscape.

Another way is to open the SVG file in a (good) text editor and to do the replace there (ideally by replacing with clones, precisely).

[EDIT] If you just need to quickly duplicate the shape on several layers, you can use the Ctrl+PgUp / PgDown shortcut. You can also remove, duplicate and move elements in the XML editor...